# Disabling of all GWT child widgets works strange

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, gwt

I need to disable all childs widgets of some custom panel. I have such method for this:

```
    public static void disableChilds(Widget widget) {
         if(widget instanceof HasWidgets) {
              Iterator<Widget> iter = ((HasWidgets) widget).iterator();
              while(iter.hasNext()) {
                  Widget element = iter.next();
                  //Window.alert(element.getClass().toString());
                  if(element instanceof HasEnabled) {
                      ((HasEnabled) element).setEnabled(false);
                  }
                  disableChilds(element);
              }
         }
    }
```

The problem is that this code works only on Firefox(24.5.0) and only if

```
      Window.alert(element.getClass().toString());
```

is uncommented. It does not want to work on Chrome(35.0.1916.114) at all.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Simply disable the root widget. I think there is no need to disable all the components.

Comment: The root widget is panel so I can't disable it I can only hide it but this is not what I need.

Comment: I don't think so that `Window.alert` is causing the issue. May be its somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I agree with  @Braj if it works in one browser, the Window.alert should not be the problem. Have you checked if any exception has appeared in your chrome's console?

Comment: I have about 5 widgets to disable so Window.alert increasing time of page rendering. But i can't understand why it works only on firefox. Another strange thing is Window.alert on chrome and on firefox alerts different widgets(on firefox it shows all child widgets and on chrome only few first of them). There is no exceptions in console

Comment: I have tested your provided code with a few TextBoxes in nested FlowPanels and it works fine in Chrome(35.0.1916.114) and gwt-2.6. I agree with @Braj. Problem must be anywhere else in your code